# Time Zone conversion Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timezone, date-conversion

I am getting this error while converting `"11-06-2018 17:00:00"` from `{(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi}` To `{(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)}`:

```
   StartDate = meetingRequest.Start.ToString(); 
   TimeZone = meetingRequest.TimeZone;

   var AllTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(); 

   foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in AllTimeZones) { 
     if (timeZoneInfo.ToString() == TimeZone) { 
       TimeZoneInfo ActualTimeZone = timeZoneInfo; 

       var MeetingWindowStartDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
            meetingRequest.Start, 
            ActualTimeZone, 
            service.TimeZone); 
      }
```

> The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime
>   did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, when the
>   Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local,  the source time zone must be
>   TimeZoneInfo.Local.\r\nParameter name: sourceTimeZone"

Comment: Please, provide the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is surely that meetingRequest.Start doesnt have a DateTimeKind so the timezone conversion cannot work because it cant assume what timezone it is converting from in the first place.

Use DateTime.SpecifyKind to set it then it should work.